# construct select to return an entity using criteria builder

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

Using JPQL I could write something similar to this:

```
select p.name, p.surname, e from Person p, Employee e
```

in this way a cartesian product is done and the full employee entity will be returned.

Using a left join:

```
SELECT p.name, p.surname, e FROM Person p LEFT JOIN p.employees e
```

I would like to create the second query using criteria builder api.
How could I do that ?

Update:
Using criteria I could do something like this:

```
      Join join = root.join("employees", JoinType.LEFT);

      CompoundSelection select = cb.array(
      root.get("name"),
      root.get("surname"),
      join)
```

But using this query I got the error:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-6044] (Eclipse
Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5):  
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException Exception Description: The primary key
read from the row [DatabaseRecord(EMPLOYEE.NUMBER => null
EMPLOYEE.ADDRESS => null)] during the execution of the query was detected to be     
null.        
Primary keys must not contain null.
```

Because eclipse link is unable to "construct" the employee object because it doesn't exist (it is a left join, so in my scenario it is possible that it doesn't exist).

Comment: Have you tried `CriteriaQuery.multiSelect(root.get("name"), root.get("surname"), join)`?

Comment: mabi: yes I tried but I got the same error.